# ldconfig shows many libraries are truncated

Tags: package-management, 18.04, shared-library

I have enjoyed using Ubuntu, as my primary OS, since the early days but have finally ran into a problem I can't fix on my own.
Every time I install updates with APT I get messages about truncated libraries. I assume this is why I can't run software that until recently was fine.

I am running a freshly installed desktop 18.04LTS 64-bit.

```
$ ldconfig
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libXdamage.so.1 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libgstapp-1.0.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libwrap.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libEGL.so.1 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libasyncns.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libvorbisenc.so.2 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libpulsecommon-8.0.so is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libselinux.so.1 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libXi.so.6 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libunbound.so.2 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.20 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libxcb-glx.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libpcre.so.3 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libffi.so.6 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libXcomposite.so.1 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libvorbis.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libsndfile.so.1 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libX11-xcb.so.1 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libogg.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.1 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libgsttag-1.0.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libgstpbutils-1.0.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/liborc-0.4.so.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 is truncated
/sbin/ldconfig.real: file /usr/lib/libjson-c.so.2 is truncated
```

I have researched this but can find nothing to help me.
If someone can get me out of this mess I will be very grateful.

PS. I really don't want to reinstall the system from scratch.

The output of `sudo ldconfig -p` is too long to show here. The first few lines are;

```
1188 libs found in cache `/etc/ld.so.cache'
    libzvbi.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzvbi.so.0
    libzvbi-chains.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzvbi-chains.so.0
    libzstd.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1
    libzmq.so.5 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5
    libzmq.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so
    libzeitgeist-2.0.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzeitgeist-2.0.so.0
```

The output of `cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` is;

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
# libc default configuration
 /usr/local/lib
# Multiarch support
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the output of `ldconfig -p` and   `cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf` ? btw: ldconfig should be run as root.

Comment: Please note I have edited the original post. It was very hard to do in such a small window. Also the reply from abua_bua was not shown whilst editing. I must be doing something wrong and making life difficult for myself...

Comment: Still really struggling with this. Can anyone help at all?

Comment: I guess not :o(

Answer (score 2):

I ran across the same error on a fresh raspbian installation for my raspberry pi.

For me reinstalling all broken libraries worked, e.g.:

```
apt install libffi6 --reinstall
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll look into it.
I have tried to reinstall some libraries but there are so many truncated entries it's going to take an age to work out which libraries they belong to.
As this computer is busy and otherwise working I really can't afford the downtime for a fresh install.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue on Ubuntu 18.04